# Can I use AWS Traffic Mirroring with ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, mirroring, network-traffic

I'm trying to find a way to relay real requests of production to test environment.
And I've found this.
https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/mirror-production-traffic-to-test-environment-with-vpc-traffic-mirroring/

However, I'm using ECS not EC2, and they comprise of ALB and ECS. So I'm wondering if this 'Traffic Mirroring' works with ECS or not, and how to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything in the blog specific to ec2.

Comment: @jordanm it says "The sources of VPC traffic mirroring are the elastic network interfaces (ENIs) of the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances"

Comment: Is your ECS cluster in your VPC?

Comment: @hephalump yes, source and destination are in the same vpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving answer for someone who might have question same with me.

After spent several hours, I could set up Traffic Mirroring from ecs to ecs.
However the automation for various port could be pretty tricky so I decided not to use traffic mirroring for traffic relay from prod to test.

I chose to use request log instead of Traffic Mirroring feature.

Comment: "request log" - do you mean ALB access log?